# GET should be for detail, but POST should not for an action method in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my application there are elements called `DemanderCollection` which are rows which contain important metadata about collections of features called `Demander`

I have a ViewSet which I use to return the `Demander` objects associated with a specific `DemanderCollection` in my database encoded as a GeoJSON (a specific kind of JSON used for exchanging geographic data), and it is bound to a special action method called `geojson`:

```
class DemanderCollectionViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

    queryset = DemanderCollection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DemanderCollectionSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def geojson(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        demanders = Demander.objects.filter(demandercollection=self.get_object())
        return Response(serialize('geojson', demanders, geometry_field='geom', fields=('name',)))
```

This special action method is set to `detail=True` because I want to return only one `DemanderCollection` worth of `Demander` features.

I would also like to allow that users can post a new `DemanderCollection` simply by posting a GeoJSON to the same endpoint (with validation to make sure the properties/columns are valid).

But the problem is that now the `geojson` method is already defined as being `detail=True`, and so I cannot post to the endpoint

```
.../api/demandercollections/geojson
```

because it is expecting there to be an id in between, like

```
.../api/demandercollections/0/geojson
```

Can I make the `geojson` endpoint ignore the `detail=True` only when making a POST request?